# How to get the current value of previous element input in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button. When I click on it, I'd like to see in the console the current input number that is right before my button element (this is not the final goal but if I can do that the rest won't be a problem).

All I get using my code is `undefined`. Can someone explain to me what's wrong and how to do?

```js
$(".ajoutPanier").click(function() {
  var nb = $(this).prev(".inputNbArt").val();
  console.log(nb); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="nbArticles">
  <input class="inputNbArt" type="number" max="10" min="1" value="1">
</form>
<a href="#openModal">
  <button class="ajoutPanier">Ajouter Au panier</button>
</a>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't put a `button` (an interactive element) inside an `a` (an interactive element), see [`button`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-button-element) and [`a`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element).

Comment: For now, on the browsers you've tested it on. It's still flatly incorrect, which means it could stop working any time.

Comment: You're right. The thing is I didn't want to change it because I would have to change a lot of things inside my css. But I guess I have to.

Answer (score 1):

There's two issues here. Firstly having a `button` element inside an `a` element is invalid HTML. I'd suggest removing the `button` and placing the `class` it had on the `a` instead. You can then use CSS to style the `a` element as needed.

Secondly, the DOM traversal method you're using isn't quite right. The `.inputNbArt` element is a child of the `form`, not a sibling to the clicked `.ajoutPanier`. To correct that, use `prev()` to get the sibling `form`, and then `find()`. Try this:

```js
$(".ajoutPanier").click(function() {
  var nb = $(this).prev('.nbArticles').find('.inputNbArt').val();
  console.log(nb); 
});
```

```css
/* example button styling */
a.ajoutPanier {
  background-color: #CCC;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="nbArticles">
  <input class="inputNbArt" type="number" max="10" min="1" value="1">
</form>
<a href="#openModal" class="ajoutPanier">Ajouter Au panier</a>
```

Comment: Thank You. It worked fine. I suppressed my <a> for now.  Just to be sure : is it impossible to open my modal with the button ?

Comment: It's not impossible, but you may need to change how the modal is triggered. I'd suggest starting a new question about that if you're having issues with it

Answer (score 0):

Because your HTML is invalid (see [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70123752/how-to-get-the-current-value-of-previous-element-input-in-jquery#comment123959209_70123752), we can't be sure what the DOM will look like in any given browser, since they can do whatever they need to to make the structure valid.

When you click the button, `this` inside the handler will be that `button` element. `prev` only finds previous **siblings**, but the element you're looking for isn't a sibling, it's a child of the button's parent's previous sibling (***if*** the browser doesn't relocate the `button`, which it very well might).

You could use:

```
$(this).parent().prev().find(".inputNbArt")
```

but it's fairly fragile. Instead, consider putting this entire structure in a parent element and then:

```
$(this).closest("selector-for-parent-element").find(".inputNbArt")
```

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m! Getting sloppy... ;-)